# Send GET request to API Gateway through a python script not authorized due to proxy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-3.6

I have set up an S3 Bucket with some Data for Clients, and want to provide them a python script they just have to execute, which then downloads the specific files they need.

For that i have built a Lambda function that returns the download links, and an API Gateway to trigger that Lambda function via GET request.

I get the expected request when i visit the url in my browser, but if i do requests.get('url') in Python 3.6, it says

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:********:<api>/<stage>/GET/<method>}
```

My script looks like this:

```
import requests
import sys


proxy = 'myproxy:myport'
username = ''
password = ''
username, password = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

https_proxy = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + proxy
http_proxy = 'http://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + proxy


proxy = {'https': https_proxy,
         'http': http_proxy}

session = requests.Session()

session.proxies = proxy

r = session.get('https://<my-api-link>')
fileDict = r.json()

print(fileDict)
```

I set up the Resource Policy of the API Gateway to Whitelist the external IP of my Company, and the clients. I confirmed this by - again - entering the api url in the browser and getting the expected result. I just want it to work via a script.

Fun thing is - when i tried it at home, where i was not behind a proxy, it worked (i previously whitelisted my ip for this of course)

Any ideas how i can fix this?
Thanks